# How to test a component composed of other components with react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am completely new to react-testing-library.  I just started reading all the various "Getting Started" documentation and blog posts I could find after I had no success testing a component with Enzyme.  Most of the examples I could find are pretty simple, like those in the ["Introducing the react-testing-library" blog post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/introducing-the-react-testing-library).  I would like to see examples of how to test a component that itself is composed of *other* components, since Component composition is one of the greatest things about React (in this SO post I will call an example of such `ComposedComponent` for lack of a better name).

When I wrote tests for a `ComposedComponented` in Enzyme, I could just assert that the correct props were passed to some `ChildComponent` and trust that `ChildComponent` had its own tests and I would not have to be concerned with what `ChildComponent` actually rendered to the DOM within my tests for `ComposedComponent`.  But with react-testing-library, I am concerned that since "rather than dealing with instances of rendered react components, your tests will work with actual DOM nodes", I will also have to test the behavior of `ChildComponent` by making assertions about the DOM nodes it renders in response to its relationship to `ComposedComponent`.  That would mean that the higher up I go in the Component hierarchy in a React application, the longer and more exhaustive my tests would become.  The gist of my question is this: **How can I test the behavior of a component that has other components as children without also testing the behavior of those child components?**

I truly hope that I am just suffering from a failure of imagination and somebody can help me figure out how to properly use this library that has gained such a following as a replacement for Enzyme.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What I do when testing components that happen to render other (already tested) components is mock them. For example, I have a component that displays some text, a button, and a modal. The modal itself is already tested so I don't want to test it again.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ComponentUnderTest } from '.';

// Mock implementation of a sub component of the component being tested
jest.mock('../Modals/ModalComponent', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    // the "default export"
    default: ({ isOpen, onButtonPress }) =>
      isOpen && (
        // Add a `testid` data attribute so it is easy to target the "modal's" close button
        <button data-testid="close" onClick={onButtonPress} type="button" />
      ),
  };
});

describe('Test', () => {
  // Whatever tests you need/want
});
```

Comment: this is neat, are there any packages that expose this nicely?

Comment: @NiRR Other than jestjs? Not that I've ever looked for or found, sorry.

Comment: I've read into this a bit and I understand why there are none. jest.mock is hoisted to the top of the file, so you can't use anything in the first or second parameters of jest.mock other than string literals or closures, leaving very little to be done in a helper library, and leaving you with very difficult code inside your test file.

Comment: @NiRR yup, very one-off code, though you could probably create a collection of mock function component literals.

Comment: This worked for me, but I get the eslint error about "Missing display name" in component definition. Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro I haven't confirmed this, but I think you could define the component function *before* the mock return, attach a `displayName` property and return as the default. Basically define the entire component with display name in the function body of the mock and return it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DrewReese, I forgot to come back here to update the status. If we use the traditional function declaration (instead of arrow function), the function name is used as `displayName` and lint will not complain :)

Comment: Something like: `default: function myComponent({ isOpen, onButtonPress }) {...`

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro Oddly enough, just now while investigating another question I came across this in refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#displaying-a-custom-name-in-devtools which basically describes the same thing for naming.